# scrapy pipelines.py file - <class 'RuntimeError'>: generator raised StopIteration pylint(astroid-error)

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
import sqlite3

class RecipesPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self,spider):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("recipes.db")
        #To use sql queries we need to create a cursor object .
        self.c = self.connection.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE FoodRecipes(
                Name TEXT,
                Ingredients TEXT,
                Directions TEXT
            )
        ''')
        self.connection.commit()

    def close_spider(self,spider):
        self.connection.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.c.execute('''
        INSERT INTO FoodRecipes(Name,Ingredients,Directions) VALUES(?,?,?)

        ''',(
            item.get('recipe_name'),
            item.get('recipe_ingredients'),
            item.get('recipe_directions')
        ))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

Hi , this is my pipelines.py file ,here i'm trying to store my scraped data into a sqlite database but i keep getting this error ": generator raised StopIteration pylint(astroid-error)" and I can't seem to find any solution to it.I'd really appreciate the help .

Comment: Could you show more information and the complete error? If you use JSON as output for `process_item` does the code work well?

Comment: @JQadrad what other information would be beneficial for the question sorry i'm kinda new to this. Also, yes if I don't use this pipelines file it works simply outputting as json.

Comment: It would be nice to see the traceback you get.